# Accounting for Seasonal Autocorrelation of Residuals in MGCV GAMMs

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, autocorrelation, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

I have been able to apply GAMs to healthcare utilization forecasting problems with great success thanks to blog posts like [this one](https://fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2014/05/09/modelling-seasonal-data-with-gam/) and others from the ever-helpful Gavin Simpson and Simon Wood. I have a cluster of questions stemming from the inability of the `corARMA()` class to model autocorrelation at multiple levels of seasonality. In particular, the data I work with nearly always have weekly autocorrelation patterns in addition to daily.

First, some simulated example data.

```
require(mgcv)
require(sarima)

set.seed(30)

n <- 1000

# simulate errors with autocorrelation at lag 1 and 7
e <- sim_sarima(list(nseasons = 7, ar = .2, sar = .5), n = n)
# counter variable
x1 <- seq_len(n)
# make a nice curvy relationship for a regression splie
x2 <- x1 / (n / 2)
y <- 2 * cospi(x2) + e
# grouping variable for weeks
x3 <- rep(rep(1:7, each = 7), length.out = n)

dat <- data.frame(y, x1, x2, x3, wkdy = factor(rep(1:7, length.out = n)))

plot(x1, y)
```

[image]

The known autocorrelation structure is recovered exactly by `acf()` after fitting an initial model.

```
m <- gam(y ~ s(x2), data = dat)
acf(residuals(m, type = 'response'))
```

[image]

It is pretty simple to account for the lag 1 autocorrelation, even if I didn't know $\phi_1$ beforehand.

```
mm1 <- gamm(
  y ~ s(x2),
  data = dat,
  correlation = corAR1(form = ~ 1)
)
coef(mm1$lme$modelStruct$corStruct, unconstrained = F)
acf(residuals(mm1$lme, type = 'normalized'))
```

```
#      Phi
# 0.189105
```

[image]

But this is where things get difficult.

Specifying the requisite grouping level in `corARMA()` does yield the correct $\phi_7$...

```
mm2 <- gamm(
  y ~ s(x2),
  data = dat,
  correlation = corAR1(form = ~ 1 | wkdy)
)
coef(mm2$lme$modelStruct$corStruct, unconstrained = F)
```

```
#      Phi
# 0.5245967
```

...however, it looks like this coefficient is applied to the lag **1** residuals when normalization is applied.

```
acf(residuals(mm2$lme, type = 'normalized'))
```

[image]

(Note that the lag 1 autocorrelation with the "correction" applied is now ~-.3, or $\phi_1-\phi_7$, and the lag 7 autocorrelation is unchanged.)

The only workaround I have been able to figure out for problems like this is to try to determine the correlation structure separately, then feed in a fixed correlation structure to `gamm()`.

```
mm3 <- gamm(
  y ~ s(x2),
  data = dat,
  correlation = corARMA(
    value = c(.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, .5),
    form = ~ 1,
    p = 7,
    fixed = T
  )
)
acf(residuals(mm3$lme, type = 'normalized'))
```

[image]

Obviously, this is much more complex when it is not known beforehand, and even when it is, fitting is slowed down a lot.

My questions are:

1. Am I doing something wrong with the ACF plot for my second model looking at weekly autocorrelation, or is this a bug in `nlme` or `mgcv`?
2. Is there any better way to approach seasonal autocorrelation in GAMMs, e.g. creating a more general correlation structure using one of the other `corStruct` constructors or something similar?
3. If not, what would it take to extend the `corStruct` class to include seasonal terms?